# Windows 10 DISM unable to find sources with WIM file

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a windows 10 laptop that whenever I open the start menu or edge, the windows will start flashing like another window is requesting focus, and then it will get focus back and I am unable to type as it loses and regains focus. I have tried doing an SFC, and it did not find any integrity violations. I have tried doing a dism restore by doing the following command with a windows iso mounted that I downloaded from TechNet, so I know the install.wim file is there.

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:WIM:G:\sources\install.wim:1
```

I've also tried a few different iterations, including removing the WIM from the soruces, removing the :1, adding /limitaccess at the end, but I get the same error message no matter what (The percentage seems to stop at random):

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.15063.0

Image Version: 10.0.15063.0

[===========================96.0%=======================   ]
Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Errors and Warnings in the log:

```
2017-07-12 16:41:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6092 TID=8284 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f081f)
2017-07-12 16:41:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6092 TID=8284 The source files could not be found; their location must be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg
2017-07-12 16:41:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6092 TID=8284 Failed processing package changes with session option CbsSessionOptionRepairStoreCorruption - CDISMPackageManager::RestoreHealth(hr:0x800f081f)
2017-07-12 16:41:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6092 TID=8284 The source files could not be found; their location must be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg
2017-07-12 16:41:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6092 TID=8284 Failed to restore the image health. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_CleanupImage(hr:0x800f081f)
2017-07-12 16:41:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6092 TID=8284 Failed while processing command cleanup-image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f081f)
```

Any ideas or do I need to reset this laptop?

Comment: The command you said you issued doesn't mount the .wim file contained in the ISO

Comment: The ISO is already mounted, I can browse to the directory containing the .wim file. Do I need to somehow mount the .wim file?

Comment: Please add the reason your running this command in the first place.  You should also submit the log file.  You mounted the ISO that doesn't mount the .wim file: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh824814.aspx

Comment: I will edit the main post with the reason I'm doing this. Also, none of the documentation I saw mentioned anything about mounting the .wim, so I'll try doing that and report back. Thanks.

Comment: "I have tried doing an SFC, and it did not find any integrity violations." - Which means DISM won't find a problem.  Does this behavior happen in a minimal configuration (no start-up applications)

Answer (score 1):

Update:

[Windows Central has an article on how to use Dism to repair an image](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image)

This article mentions using /restorehealth with an install.wim file source. According to them, my initial suggestion was correct: the syntax needs to be adjusted (The screen shot below is from their article).

[image: A screen shot from their article showing the correct code]

Original post:

I've used dism a fair amount--although never for this particular purpose-- and I have used the /source option frequently. It's been my experience that this error indicates that there is a typo or invalid syntax in the file path.

I've highlighted where I believe the syntax error is:

[image: /sources:WIM:G:]

Get rid of WIM and try:

```
/sources:G:\Sources\install.wim
```

Comment: You are incorrect. I've updated my post with a screen shot from Windows Central that shows the correct syntax.  And a link to the article.

Comment: I don't think it is. Check the article. It's that sources:WIM:G:\ I've NEVER seen "WIM" between the ':' and the error message says it can't find the file. That suggests the path is incorrect.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of the syntax working in Windows 10? DISM is a beast, and it's possible it worked on an older version of Windows. And I may have been hasty to say you aren't correct, so I apologize. DISM is way too complicated to claim to know it with certainty.